# Android - Alterar componentes de um Dialog

Tags: java, android

Usei um Dialog para exibir um alerta personalizado desta forma:

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog();
dialog.setContextView(R.layout.resource);
dialog.setTitle("Diálogo");
dialog.show();
```

Porém eu não consigo alterar elementos do xml do Dialog usando essa Activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primeiro crie um elemento na classe Java e depois recupere ele do Dialog. Por exemplo:

```
public void dialogClick() {

   Dialog dialog = new Dialog();
   dialog.setContextView(R.layout.resource);
   dialog.setTitle("Diálogo");
   dialog.show();

   View = dialog.findViewById(R.id.sua_view);
   view.setOnClickListener(ASuaListener());

}
```